# Why is this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion

As the title says I wonder why this is downvoted so much:
[Parental Controls on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/937479/423684)

It is a newbie to Ask Ubuntu and no one wrote any comments about what is probably wrong with his/her question.

I see parents who want to protect their childs on an Ubuntu System.
Ok there is not a lot detailed information but nobody asked for them neither.

Maybe Ask Ubuntu isn't the right spot where to ask this so where would you ask a question like that rather?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I am wondering how I would set up parental controls on my personal computer. I would also like to force safe search on all search engines. "

was the original question. The downvotes are more than likely to represent a lack of effort by the creator of the question.

Look at for instance [What is the best way to restrict access to adult content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content)

Looks a lot better. It shows a lot more effort. So it is worth the 60 upvotes it got. A clear duplicate that is better worded in all regards.

Instead it has 2 sentences that each will have a different answer. The 1st one asked about parental controls on the operating system. The 2nd asks about limiting browser functionality. Also those answers will take a lot of time to create and the 2 sentences leave a lot of room for interpretation on what is asked (For me personally an answer that would take more than 30 minutes to create needs a decent question or I will not bother with it).

Comment: Ok fair enough makes sence to me, thanks. Just bothered me a bit that people just voted him down without leaving any helpful comment since he is new to Ask Ubuntu..